# How To Push Gatling Perf Results To EC2 Grafana/InfluxDB instance

Tags: grafana, influxdb, gatling

I have spun an t2.micro Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance and in this EC2 instance i have installed manually Grafana and InfluxDB .
Both Grafana and InfluxDB have been installed successfully with no errors,but now what i expect is when i run Gatling tests at my 
windows local ,results should get pushed live to InfluxDB and eventually to Grafana

Here is my extract of Gatling.conf settings

```
data {
 writers = [console, file, graphite]      # The list of DataWriters to which Gatling write simulation data (currently supported : console, file, graphite, jdbc)
 console {
  #light = false                # When set to true, displays a light version without detailed request stats
  #writePeriod = 5              # Write interval, in seconds
   }

 graphite {
  light = false              # only send the all* stats
  host = "http://ec2-54-67-97-86.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
  port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
  protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
  rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
  bufferSize = 8192          # GraphiteDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
  writeInterval = 1          # GraphiteDataWriter's write interval, in seconds
}
```

Problem is I see no data in influx instance when i run my Gatling tests from local

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-16:~$ influx -host ec2-54-67-97-86.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com                                                    Connected to http://ec2-54-67-97-86.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8086 version 1.7.7
InfluxDB shell version: 1.7.7
> show databases
name: databases
name
----
_internal
gatling
graphite
> use graphite
Using database graphite
> show series
key
---
X-Grafana-Org-Id:
```

Can someone help to debug this ,that why no data is being received at influx DB

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check your graphite listener in influx.

To do it open your `influxdb.conf` and find `[[graphite]]` block.

For default settings it should look like that:

```
[[graphite]]
  # Determines whether the graphite endpoint is enabled.
  enabled = true
  database = "gatlingdb"
  retention-policy = ""
  bind-address = ":2003"
  protocol = "tcp"
  consistency-level = "one"

  templates = [
       "gatling.*.*.*.* measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
       "gatling.*.users.*.*measurement.simulation.measurement.request.field"
  ]
```

More info here: https://gatling.io/docs/current/realtime_monitoring/#influxdb